# Ruby: libxml-ruby and adding nicely-formatted sibling nodes

Tags: xml, ruby, formatting, libxml-ruby

Given my existing XML (test.xml):

```
<root>
  <element>
    <child id="1" />
    <child id="2" />
    <child id="3" />
  </element>
</root>
```

And my ruby code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'xml'

parser = XML::Parser.file("test.xml")
doc = parser.parse

target = doc.find('/*/element')
target << child = XML::Node.new('child')
child['id'] = '4'

XML.indent_tree_output = true
doc.save(filename, :indent => true, :encoding => XML::Encoding::UTF_8)
```

My problem is that it formats the output like this:

```
<root>
  <element>
    <child id="1" />
    <child id="2" />
    <child id="3" />
  <child id="4" /></element>
</root>
```

... with subsequent additions looking like this:

```
<root>
  <element>
    <child id="1" />
    <child id="2" />
    <child id="3" />
  <child id="4" /><child id="5" /><child id="6" /></element>
</root>
```

What I **WANT** is this:

```
<root>
  <element>
    <child id="1" />
    <child id="2" />
    <child id="3" />
    <child id="4" />
    <child id="5" />
    <child id="6" />
  </element>
</root>
```

... but how do I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace 
`parser = XML::Parser.file("test.xml")`

with 
`parser = XML::Parser.file("test.xml", :options => XML::Parser::Options::NOBLANKS )`

that's help

Answer (score 0):

If you're using document.save then make sure you set indent to true, also make sure XML.indent_tree_output is set. Something like this:

```
XML.indent_tree_output = true
doc.save(filename, :indent => true, :encoding => XML::Encoding::UTF_8)
```

Rubyforge isn't working for me so I can't verify it in the documentation, but I think both need to be set to true for indenting and new lines to work.

Comment: Forgot to add that line into my question, but it was there in my original file and I still had the issue. "test.xml" is originally created from scratch by another section of my code; I'm just having issues adding nodes into an existing file.  Rubyforge isn't working for me either...